# Performance in Entity Framework Foreach Add elements

Tags: sql, performance, entity-framework, foreach

I have a program to add points of interest and it's guides from a webservice to a data base, it looks like this:

```
// For all the cities (like 1M)
foreach(City city in ListOfCities){
    try {
        AddCity(city);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        _logger.Error(ex.Message);
        continue;
    }
}

//save points of interest of the city to the database
public void AddCity(City city){
    using (WEntities context = new WEntities()){
        //for all the points of interest
        foreach(PointOfInterest point in city){
            try{
                //search all the guides and add them to the point of interest
                List<Guide> listGuides = _webservice.GetAllGuidesForPoint(point);
                foreach(Guide guide in listGuides){
                    point.Guides.Add(guide);
                }
                // add the point to the context and save it to the database
                context.PointOfInterest.AddObject(point);
                context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(point, System.Data.EntityState.Added);
                context.SaveChanges();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                _logger.Error(ex.Message)
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that given a number of cities, the speed of each iteration drop significantly, at first each loop may take 1 second, and in the end can take more than 30 minutes.

What I'm doing wrong? Can I do something to make all the iterations to take the same time (the short one, if I can choose)?

P.D.: what's more, the cpu and ram usage increments over the time.

Comment: I don't think EF is the bottleneck here; you're awaiting for `_webservice.GetAllGuidesForPoint()` method. Check the return time of that method.

Comment: I will look for it, but do you tink that it's that method fault that every loop takes more time and consumes more resources?

Comment: Actually, that is only a part of the problem. The resource consumption is due to EF change tracking mechanism; basically, when you're adding an object to the data context you're also adding the required data to keep track and state of that object which can take significant amount of memory when you insert a lot of data. I suggest using `SqlBulkCopy` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) for inserting large sets of data.

Comment: I'm gona try this library too, it looks good.